# How do I add user inputs on click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, state, storage

Self taught coder. Hopefully I can explain this adequately. Users create recipe cooking guides by inputing values like dish name, food category, cover img, etc. The steps array only has 1 step at the moment. I want a button that users can click that would add another "step" and "gif" to the steps array. Can anyone suggest a method to have another set of "step" and "img" render on screen when the user clicks the Add Step button? I have a handleAddSteps function with nothing inside. Somebody recommended using DOM? Just want to know if this is a good way to go before investing time down the wrong rabbit hole. Thank you kindly for any advice.

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

// Styles
import "./UploadGuide.scss";

// Firebase
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db, storage } from "../../firebase";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import { ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";


function UploadGuide() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState("");
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [percentage, setPercentage] = useState(null);
  // const [stepsCounter, setStepsCounter] = useState(0);

  // Upload IMG
  useEffect(() => {
    const uploadFile = () => {
      
      const name = new Date().getTime() + file.name;
      const storageRef = ref(storage, file.name);
      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);
      uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snapshot) => {
          const progress =
            (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
          console.log("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
          setPercentage(progress);
          switch (snapshot.state) {
            case "paused":
              console.log("Upload is paused");
              break;
            case "running":
              console.log("Upload is running");
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        },
        () => {
          // Handle successful uploads on complete
          getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
            setData((prev) => ({ ...prev, img: downloadURL }));
          });
        }
      );
    };
    file && uploadFile();
  }, [file]);

  console.log(file);
  console.log(data);

  // When user clicks Add Steps button, page renders another steps card
  const handleAddSteps = () => {};

  // When user submits guide, upload data to firecloud db and imgs to firebase storage.
  const handleAddGuide = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newId = uuidv4();
    // const stepsArray = []
    await setDoc(doc(db, "guides", newId), {
      author: e.target.author.value,
      categoryId: "100",
      categoryName: e.target.categoryName.value,
      coverGif: data.img,
      id: newId,
      name: e.target.name.value,
      tags: e.target.tags.value,
      // steps: stepsArray
      steps: [
        {
          step: e.target.step.value,
          gif: data.img,
        },
      ],
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="upload">
      <form onSubmit={handleAddGuide} className="upload__form">
        <div className="upload__card">
          <div className="upload__inputs">
            <label className="upload__label">Guide Name</label>
            <input
              className="upload__input"
              placeholder="Name of your recipe"
              type="name"
              name="name"
              // value=""
            ></input>
          </div>
          <div className="upload__inputs">
            <label className="upload__label">Author</label>
            <input
              className="upload__input"
              type="author"
              name="author"
            ></input>
          </div>
          <div className="upload__inputs">
            <label className="upload__label">Category</label>
            <select
              name="categoryName"
              className="upload__input"
              defaultValue={"Cooking"}
            >
              <option value="Cooking">Cooking</option>
              <option></option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div className="upload__inputs">
            <label className="upload__label">Tags</label>
            <input
              name="tags"
              className="upload__input upload__input--large"
              placeholder="Add relevant tags to help people find your guide"
            ></input>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="upload__card upload__card--addstep">
          <div className="upload__inputs">
            <label className="upload__label">Step 1</label>
            <input
              className="upload__input upload__input--large"
              name="step"
            ></input>
          </div>
          <div className="upload__inputs">
            <div>
              <img src={file ? URL.createObjectURL(file) : ""}></img>
            </div>
            <label
              htmlFor="file"
              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
              className="upload__add"
            >
              + IMG
            </label>
            <input
              id="file"
              onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])}
              style={{ display: "none" }}
              type="file"
            ></input>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="upload__box">
        <button
          className="upload__add"
          onClick={handleAddSteps}
          style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
        >
          Add Step
        </button>
        </div>
        <div className="upload__cta">
          <button
            disabled={percentage !== null && percentage < 100}
            type="submit"
            className="upload__submit"
            style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
          >
            Upload
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default UploadGuide;
```

Here is an image of what the page looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhPPb.png)

Please let me know if I'm missing any key information. Any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't sound like this question has anything to do with Firebase. It sounds more like you need help with basic  javascript coding? e.g. "how do I add a button and make it do something" or "how do I add several buttons"? Maybe if you can clarify what's being asked, we maybe able to provide some help.

Comment: Thanks Jay. I appreciate the comment. I think learning to explain problems better is a skill in of itself! I will try and provide more context. I added an image for reference of what the page looks like. Basically, I need the ADD STEP button to add another STEP and GIF upload card (Duplicate the right side of the image in the black box). Every time that ADD STEP is clicked, another card generates. Furthermore, when you upload a new gif or img to the step, the handleGuide function would need to update the STEPS array to contain all the added steps the user added. Hope this helps a bit?

Comment: There are two variables, data and e, we dont know how you initialize them, and even where you call handleAddGuide, please share the whole code

Comment: Thank you for the comment Hans, you are right, my apologies. I have updated my post to include all the code. Hope this helps clarify how everything is working. Appreciate any further advice.

Answer (score 0):

Since each Guide can have multiple steps, I would rather create a state that handles an array of multiple step objects, than just a counter.
With this, you can render as much steps as you have in the array.
Then, adding steps just will be a matter of adding objects (with an empty state) to that array.

I made this functional example, that should be clear enough to show what I mean:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const EMPTY_STEP = { text: '', file: null };

export default function App() {
  const [guideSteps, setGuideSteps] = useState([{ ...EMPTY_STEP }]);

  const handleStepChange = (stepIndex, property, value) => {
    setGuideSteps((prevState) => {
      const newGuideSteps = [...prevState];
      newGuideSteps[stepIndex] = { ...newGuideSteps[stepIndex], [property]: value };

      return newGuideSteps;
    });
  };

  const handleAddStep = () => {
    setGuideSteps((prevState) => [...prevState, { ...EMPTY_STEP }]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="Steps">
      {guideSteps.map((step, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={`step-${index + 1}`}>
            <h2>{`Step ${index + 1}`}</h2>
            <input type="text" value={step.text} onChange={(e) => handleStepChange(index, 'text', e.target.files ? e.target.files[0] : null, index)} />
            <input type="file" value={step.file} onChange={(e) => handleStepChange(index, 'file', e.target.value, index)} />
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <button onClick={handleAddStep}>Add Step</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that example Max. I definitely see what you mean and that's super helpful. I think I'm getting closer. I can now add steps and they render on screen on button click, however my handleAddGuide function is totally busted haha. I'll try and rework it. Thanks again for taking the time. I'm headed in the right direction.